# Why are .sql files opening automatically when highlighted in the 'Navigate To' search in VS15?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I was a bit surprised I couldn't find anyone else with this issue, as it has become quite an annoyance at times.

In any of my VS(2015) projects, when I'm searching for a file, I use the 'Navigate To' (CTRL + ,) search bar. A certain behavior I've noticed is that whenever a '.sql' file has been highlighed in this search, it instantly opens the file as if I had pressed Enter.

Part of the issue is some projects have many stored procedures with parts of their filename similar to files in the project, so I may be typing in a search and as soon as any .sql file shows as the first result in the list, it opens before I can finish typing the entire search query.

Can anyone else please confirm this bug, and perhaps if it has been fixed in VS2017?